# Кастомный слушатель запросов

Tags: android, retrofit, callback

В `Retrofit` в `onResponse` может прийти `Response = null`. Чтобы начать обработку ответа, надо проверить его на `isSuccessful`. Не хочется везде писать эту проверку, можно ли как-то написать кастомный `Callback` и в нем, проверить успешный ли ответ и если нет - то вызвать `onFailure`? Еще мне хотелось бы, чтобы в `onResponse` приходил уже готовый обьект, без обертки в `Response`. А в `onFailure` вообще ничего не приходило. Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
/**
 * Basic callback for API
 *
 * @param <T> success data type
 */
abstract class ApiCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        if (response == null || !response.isSuccessful())
            onFailure(call, new Exception(...));
    }
}
```

В своём коде используйте данный класс как базовый (вместо `Callback`), и не забудьте вызывать `super.onResponse(call, response)` до своего кода в `onResponse`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте аннотацию @NonNull, чтобы не делать каждый раз проверки Response на null.

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
...
call.enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
        @Override
public void onResponse(Call<T> call, @NonNull Response<T> response) {
}

        @Override
public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure", t);
        }
});
```

Если же вы хотите получать уже готовый объект, а не обёртку Response, то могу посоветовать использование RxJava, RxAndroid:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.5'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'

public interface MessagesApi {
@GET("messages1.json")
Single<List<Message>> messages();
}

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://rawgit.com/startandroid/data/master/messages/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
 MessagesApi messagesApi = retrofit.create(MessagesApi.class);

    messagesApi.messages()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<Message>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull List<Message> messages) {

                        Log.d("OkHttp", "onSuccess: message size = " + messages.size());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
                    Log.d("OkHttp", "onError: ", e);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Аннотация `NonNull` используется только при **компиляции**